# How to get the last ListView column

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a ListView with 6 columns. How do I change the text on the last one?

Here is the full code:

```
string clientdata = Encoding.Default.GetString(data); 
string[] str = clientdata.Split('~'); 
listView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text = str[0]; 
listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text = str[1]; 
listView1.Items[i].SubItems[4].Text = str[2]; 
listView1.Items[i].SubItems[5].Text = str[3]; // Error here
break;
```

But I get the error:

> `InvalidArgument` Value of '5' is not valid for 'index'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From MSDN:

> The first subitem in the ListViewItem.ListViewSubItemCollection is
>   always the item that owns the subitems. When performing operations on
>   subitems in the collection, be sure to reference index position 1
>   instead of 0 to make changes to the first subitem.

So the first subitem is `subItem[1]` and so it should be:

```
string clientdata = Encoding.Default.GetString(data); 
string[] str = clientdata.Split('~'); 
listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text = str[0]; 
listView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text = str[1]; 
listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text = str[2]; 
listView1.Items[i].SubItems[4].Text = str[3]; 
break;
```

Suppose you have x columns: 
`ListviewItem.SubItems[0]` represents the first column
`ListviewItem.SubItems[1]` represents the second column
`ListviewItem.SubItems[x-1]` represents the last column

Comment: Thanks i made it :) Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
listView1.Items[i].SubItems[listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Count - 1].Text
```

Or use Linq's [`Last`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.last.aspx) extension method:

```
listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Cast<ListViewSubItem>().Last().Text
```

Comment: It's strange but second option (`listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Cast<ListViewItem>().Last().Text`) doesn't work.

Comment: InvalidArgument=Value of '5' is not valid for 'index'.

Comment: No error, simply doesn't modify the text (VS2012 .NET4.5), at first I think the same solution as you and testing it surprise me (the first works fine of course).

Comment: the second option gaved me: Unable to cast object of type 'ListViewSubItem' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem'.

Comment: an the first just doesn't put the text, but it gives me no errors

Comment: @KraziiKiiD Sorry that should've been `.Cast<ListViewSubItem>()` see my updated answer.

Comment: Ok it's `System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem` and with this works fine.

Comment: ok so someone just write me the code..pls..i don't know what should i finally type

Comment: by this listView1.Items[i].SubItems[listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Count - 1].Text it changes is but not the last one, it changes is the previous one, and then i changed -1 with -0 and it give me again InvalidArgument=Value of '5' is not valid for 'index'.

Comment: @KraziiKiiD It sounds like there might be a problem elsewhere in your code (e.g. if you're inserting a new item after this, it will appear like your updating the second-to-last item).

Comment: @KraziiKiiD Are you absolutely sure that your list view has 6 columns at that point in the code? Set a break point at that point and verify that `listView1.Items[i].SubItems.Count == 6`.

Comment: it has 6 columns from display index 0 to 5

Comment: so what should i try?